# Definition of adjunction space in M.A. Armstrongs Basic Topology

Tags: general-topology

I’m having a problem with a notation in the book Basic Topology by M.A. Armstrong.

In this book Armstrong discusses a special type of identification space which is generated by attaching one space to another by means of a continous function (which is commonly called an adjunction space).

Armstrong begins by considering two topological spaces X and Y and a subspace A of Y with a continous function $f: A \to X$. Then the author looks at the disjoint union $X+Y$ and defines the subsets of a partition of $X+Y$ as follows:

a) $\{a,f(a) \}$, where $a \in A$

b) individual points of $Y \setminus A$

c) individual points of $X$ $\setminus$ $image(f)$

My issue is that I do not think that this partition is well-defined in cases where f is not injective, for if we have $a_1, a_2 \in A$ where $a_1  \neq a_2$ and $f(a_1)=f(a_2)$ then the sets $\{a_1,f(a_1) \}$, $\{a_2,f(a_2) \}$ are not disjoint, seemingly contradicting the definition of a partition. Am I overlooking something or does the definition of subsets of type a) have to be rephrased?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct partition is $\{x\}\cup f^{-1}(x)$. That is, you pick $x$ in the range of $f$ and declare $x\sim y\Leftrightarrow y\in f^{-1}(x)$ so basically you select an $x$ and identify it with its fiber under $f$. These sets are obviously disjoint. If $x$ is not in the image of $f$, you only identify it with itself. If $y$ is not in the domain of $f$, you only identify it with itself.

Now check that these definitions give you an equivalence relation on $X+Y.$

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is not correct. You have to replace a) by

a') $\{x\} + f^{-1}(x)$  where  $ x \in f(A)$.